# Spring Data Crate custom queries

Tags: spring-data, crate

I am trying to implement Spring Data Crate API in a project. Following the instructions provided here:

https://crate.io/a/using-sprint-data-crate-with-your-java-rest-application/

Inserts/Updates/FindById methods are covered. My question is how to create custom queries using this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at our Spring Data adapter?

> Declared Queries
>
> It's also possible to use the `@Query` annotation to define queries:
>
> ```
> public interface UserRepository extends CrateRepository<User, String> {
>
>     @Query("select * from users")
>     List<User> getAllUsers();
> }
> ```

https://github.com/crate/spring-data-crate#declared-queries

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

please note that the crate java-client is not supported anymore since v0.57 unfortunately.

> https://crate.io/docs/clients/java/

This leaves us with the java-jdbc:

> https://github.com/crate/crate-sample-apps/blob/master/java/documentation.md

Spring data adapter is using the java-client.

Here is a Spring Boot application that is using JDBC in order to access CrateDB (> v0.57.0) https://github.com/klearchos/crate

And here are the official samples in order to access CreateDB through JDBC (using the Spark framework). https://github.com/crate/crate-sample-apps/tree/master/java